# VSTS npm unable to set NODE_ENV

Tags: npm, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am unable to set NODE_ENV in VSO release management. In development the npm script runs fine.

```
"start:dev": "SET NODE_ENV=development&&gulp dev-serve"
```

But in VS Team Services release management when I run the npm task with the command I get an error that the command is unrecognized.

```
"start:prod": "SET NODE_ENV=production&&gulp prod-serve"
```

How do I set NODE_ENV in production?

Comment: Do you have a script start:prod defined in your package.json?

Comment: Yes i have. Like I mentioned in development it works fine. it doesn't work in the Team Services Release definition.

Comment: Can you share the script section in package.json and the detailed error logs?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT thanks but I stumbled upon the solution while playing around with webpack :). Details below.

Answer (score 0):

I modified my build process a bit and in turn made me realize the issue. I was using gulp to generate a config file and kick off my webpack process which needed the file. Mainly because I had started with gulp and hadn't yet figured out how to use webpack for config management. I then found that using the gulp command as one of the npm commands was the issue. I replaced it with webpack and it runs fine.

This does not work

```
"start": "SET NODE_ENV=production&&gulp serve"
```

This works

```
"start": "SET NODE_ENV=production&&webpack -p"
```

I then found that there is a gulp task in VSTS. So you need to use that to run a gulp task. You can set env using a command prompt task and then run the gulp task.